# How can I sync Music from the phone to Onedrive?

Tags: sync, onedrive

Has anyone found an app for Windows Phone 8 that can synchronize the music on the phone with a Music folder on Onedrive?

The Onedrive app allows me to view the music in Onedrive but doesn't support sync like the desktop app does. I also need to have the music (actually podcasts) loaded locally to the phone and not streamed. Lastly, I want it to be a two-way sync so that when I delete a podcast after listening to it on the phone, it is eventually removed from Onedrive as well.

There are a number of Onedrive/Music apps that I found but they're all geared to either streaming only or require manual downloading (and no syncing of deletes). Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this automatically.

Music in the Music+Videos hub is synced with your Xbox Music Collection (not a specific folder in OneDrive.) However, the Music+Video isn't very good at detecting changes.

I've been using the Xbox Music beta app for the past couple of weeks, and while it is a little slower, it is better at syncing your collection. The [app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/groove-music/9wzdncrfj3pt) requires you to have an Xbox Music pass to use. It also doesn't support Podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

The syncing of files via Onedrive to zune music is not yet supported.